# Disable HTTP Interceptor in a certain page (angular)

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I found the source code that intercepts HTTP requests and display the erros as intended, but I really don't want to change the source code of the Angular Module.

I really need to disable it in a single page. Is there a way to do so? Could somebody point me to a direction?

Thank you!

[image: EXCEPTION]

EDIT > I have found a workaround

https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/abp-ng2-module/issues/3#issuecomment-336222390

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable for particular AJAX calls by adding `abpHandleError: false` into abp.ajax options.

Related issue: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/1301

Comment: Ok, if you are working with angular4 this is not possible. I have editted my response to add a workaround